# How send unknown number of inputs texts into create action in MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, query-string

In my Create View, I have a form that the user decides how many objects to add to the database.
Lets say the DB is for a Recipe site, so in add recipe you will have 1 textbox for RecipeName, but the number of ingredients change from one recipe to another, so I let the user add textboxes with Jquery.
now, after the user presses the submit button, I want to manually get the Querystring and order them by the inputbox name.

my question is how do I get the Querystring in the create action?

I tried to use the Request.QueryString[], but it returns null.

thanks in advance,
Nimi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Add a ViewModel class:

   public class RecipeViewModel
   {

   ```
     public string ReceipeName {get; set;}

     public List<string> ingredients {get; set;}
   ```

   }
2. Bind your view to this ViewModel
3. Now use Jquery/Javascript to give user facility to add ingredients .

Comment: On number 2 - do you mean to do "@model ViewModel"? I did that, now, inside my @using (Html.BeginForm())
{} I have 2 textboxes, and the Create ActionResult gets (ViewModel model). But once I run the website and fill the textboxes, nothing is passed to the ActionResult. Any ideas why?

Comment: yes, you need to create and bind your view with RecipeViewModel.

Comment: your Create ActionResult will gets (RecipeViewModel model)

Comment: Worked out GREAT!! I think I'll manage from here. I made a few Lists in the RecipeViewModel that get all the recipe properties, now, once I pass them to the controller, I can "Unwrap" the lists and bind them together myself.

Comment: Cigano, What does the BeginCollectionItem exactly do?

Comment: Bappi - What is the right way to add a new @Html.TextBoxFor(model=>model.ingredients[0]) using jJQuery?

Answer (score 0):

I think it's the case to use `BeginCollectionItem`:

[MVC 3 Dynamic Form Using a ViewModel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9314058/mvc-3-dynamic-form-using-a-viewmodel)

It is available in NuGet as a package:

https://www.nuget.org/packages/BeginCollectionItem/